# RouteTable.Routes.GetVirtualPath() bug with multiple optional parameter?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes, optional-parameters

In my ASP.NET MVC 4 mobile application, I have a route defined as:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "GraveNavigation",
                url: "Unites/{development}/{field1}/{field2}/{field3}/{field4}/{field5}", //each development have unique location hierarchy. One may have Section/Block/Path/Lot/Unit, another may only have Block/Lot/Unit.
                defaults: new
                        {
                            controller = "Unit",
                            action = "Index",
                            development= UrlParameter.Optional,
                            field1 = UrlParameter.Optional,
                            field2 = UrlParameter.Optional,
                            field3 = UrlParameter.Optional,
                            field4 = UrlParameter.Optional,
                            field5 = UrlParameter.Optional
                        }
            );
```

If I use the method in this page, I will always get a null vdp IF I HAVE MORE THAN FOUR(4) OPTIONAL PARAMETERS. Therefore, with `"Unites/{development}/{field1}/{field2}/{field3}"`, it works ok and I get a valid `VirtualPathData`. Once I have `"Unites/{development}/{field1}/{field2}/{field3}/{field4}..."` as route URL, `RouteTable.Routes.GetVirtualPath` always return null.

If I use `@Url.RouteUrl` utility on a View, I can construct an  tag but with the same problem:

```
var v = oneLevelInTheHierarchy;

<a href='@Url.Action("Index", new { cemetery = v.development, field1 = v.field1, field2 = v.field2, field3 = v.field3, field4 = v.field4 })'>@v.Name</a>
```

This takes hours to figure out and there are very limited discussion online. Therefore, this makes me wander if asp.net 4 routing supports more than 4 optional parameters?

Or if I use the method incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use use a catchall:

```
  routes.MapRoute(
            name: "GraveNavigation",
            url: "Unites/{development}/{*fields}"
            ...);
```